# How to install Linux Mint's Mate Fork on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, installation, mint, mate

The Title explains itself.  I want to install Linux Mint's Mate, but I want to keep Ubuntu.  Is it possible to get it?  And if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

See the install guide

http://wiki.mate-desktop.org/download

and

http://wiki.mate-desktop.org/replace_unity_by_mate

As MATE is not in the Ubuntu repositories, support here is likely to be limited.

Comment: Is this the version of Mate that come with Mint?